# Document is created, but with incorrect filename and saved on incorrect location

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that is checking whether a documents exists on a specific location and if not it is created and saved to that specific location.

The code for checking is correct, however when a document is not existing a document is created, but it is saved to the top folder with a filename that is the folderpath + filename. The folder where the document should be saved does exist.

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Thank you in advance.

**Example:**

I double click to open 'Cover letter', it is not present so it should be created and saved as follows:

L:Templates/1.0 Cover Letter/Cover Letter.docx

Instead it is created and saved as follows:

L:Templates/1.0 Cover Letter_Cover Letter.docx

```
Public Sub subTemplate()

''this macro creates an empty template document with header and property information
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_templates").Column).Activate
    
    Range("zz_preventloop").Value = "x"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
          
    Dim DocType As String
    If Range("zz_officeversion").Value = "previous to 2007" Then
    DocType = ".doc"
    Else
    DocType = ".docx"
    End If
        

'check the document type
    If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_doctype_template").Column).Value = ".url" Then ''Opening the .url shortcut
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Range("zz_envelope_templates").Value + "/" + ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_locations_temp").Column).Value + "/" _
        + ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_hidden_eDMStemp").Column).Value + ".url", NewWindow:=True
    Else
        If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_doctype_template").Column).Value = ".docx" Then
            Application.Calculate
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Word = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
            If Word Is Nothing Then
                Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            End If
        'to check if the template already exists:
            Dim filename As String
            filename = Range("zz_envelope_templates").Value + "/" + ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_locations_temp").Column).Value + "/" _
            + ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_hidden_eDMStemp").Column).Value + DocType
            filename = Replace(filename, "<", "[")
            filename = Replace(filename, ">", "]")
            If Dir(filename) = "" Then
            'to return to activesheet (QQ) after selection (because of activating sheet 'Header')
                Dim QQ As String
                QQ = ActiveSheet.Name
                Dim propTitle As String
                Dim propSubject As String
                propTitle = Range("zz_envelope_title").Value ''Property Title (= CTD Name)
                propSubject = Range("zz_envelope_OFN").Value ''Property Subject (= Output Filename)
                Application.GoTo Range("zz_envelope_header")
                Selection.COPY ''Copy the header information from sheet 'Header', the script to paste this is within the 'Template' document
                Sheets(QQ).Activate
                Word.Visible = True
            'create properties from previously created strings
                Word.Documents.Open (Range("zz_envelope_templates").Value + "\template" + DocType)
                Word.Activedocument.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Title") = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_CTD").Column).Value
                Word.Activedocument.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Subject") = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_OFN").Column).Value
                If Len(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_header_CTDnr").Column).Value) > 0 Then
                    Word.Activedocument.CustomDocumentProperties("CTDnrHeader") = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_header_CTDnr").Column).Value + " "
                Else
                    Word.Activedocument.CustomDocumentProperties("CTDnrHeader") = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_header_CTDnr").Column).Value
                End If
                Word.Activedocument.CustomDocumentProperties("SubjectHeader") = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_header_subject").Column).Value
                Word.Activedocument.CustomDocumentProperties("TitleHeader") = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_header_title").Column).Value
                Word.Activedocument.CustomDocumentProperties("SubtitleHeader") = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_header_subtitle").Column).Value
                Word.Activate
                Word.Activedocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VIEW.SeekView = 10 ''footer field update
                Word.Selection.WholeStory
                Word.Selection.Fields.Update
                Word.Activedocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VIEW.SeekView = 9 ''header fields update
                Word.Selection.WholeStory
                Word.Selection.Fields.Update
                Word.Activedocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.VIEW.SeekView = 0 ''main document
                AppActivate Application.Caption
                Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveSheet.Range("zz_hidden_tempID").Column).Value = Word.Activedocument.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Category")
                Word.Activate
                Word.Activedocument.SaveAs filename:=Replace(filename, "/", "_") ''Document now saved on the eDMS home location
            Else
                Word.Visible = True
                Word.Documents.Open (filename)
                Word.Activate
                AppActivate Application.Caption
                Word.Activate
                Word.Activedocument.Save
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Range("zz_preventloop").Value = ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks that you try building the path using slash "/" as path separator, instead of "\". Can you show us what values do "zz_envelope_templates", "zz_envelope_templates" etc. have, in order to understand how `filename` has been built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Activedocument.SaveAs filename:=Replace(filename, "/", "_")` produces the result which you describe.

Please, try the next code line instead:

```
Activedocument.SaveAs filename:=Replace(filename, "/", "\")
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Activedocument.SaveAs filename:=Replace(filename, "/", "\")`? Excel-VBA uses "\" for paths.

Comment: @MG92 Yes, you are right. I did not observe that it is a slash. I did not look to the code above this line which clearly looked to be the problematic one. I thought it was backslash... Corrected.